# Zoomable offline map

Tags: images, maps, offline

I usually receive addresses from people to use map(No addresses on net)which must be highest resolution, I often don't know where **somewhere unplanned** is.

Just an image is fine but better if it is:

1. zoomable
2. usable on Android
3. software with search, directions, and placemarking
4. satellite view

Google Maps and other apps only download one resolution.

I have a Linux machine, but I'll install Windows if needed.

Comment: It can be just one huge image instead if there isn't software for that yet

Comment: "and other apps" obviously doesn't include *Locus Maps*, which downloads multiple resolutions and can even deal with vector maps. Could you please check [these answers](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=locus+user%3A185) and say if this app would fit your needs?

Comment: @Izzy I see you are a OpenStreetMaps proponent, I'm reading through the wiki and I keep opening new wiki articles, not finding how to import satellite maps into android.I've found these satellite imagery but how do I use it? http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Geoportal.gov.pl

Comment: @Izzy My approach has been to find a program that can work with these satellite images and can export the maps to a fiel soem androdi app can use.

Comment: I'm using OSM (and all kind of other map sources, whichever fit), but I never *edited* maps. In *Locus*, you simply select your source and chose which kind of map to download in which "resolution levels", and that's it. You can try with the free version to see whether it fits.

Comment: @Izzy I've tried locus but it got stuck at `working` afetr downloading.I just want to have these maps satellite if possible too

Comment: I see – in that case, it's not a solution for you. I've never heard of a suitable solution working that way (i.e. with the entire maps and POIs and search, directions, etc. exchangeable between all environments). You can have the *data* exchangeable (`.kmz`/`.gpx` etc.), but not the entire software, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Izzy Is there a solution juts for zoomable satellite maps? (without search, directions, etc)

Comment: Probably there is, but I'm not aware of it. As I wrote, I use the mapping software, and the maps with it, but not the maps separately, sorry. Maps themselves are just data, so that would basically not be a *Software Recommendation* and tus off-topic here. Hint: Please read carefully the [conditions for GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) whether asking for "map material" might be on-topic there. I'm not sure whether it is, as I'm not active over there.

Comment: @Izzy it doesn't have to be just a map.It will be better if it is software with an offline map.That's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Osmand Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand) for Android, after investigating several offline mapping programs for Android.

The interface takes some getting used to; it's not the most intuitive so you have a learning curve. The maps are based on OpenStreetMap data, they are available for most places as far as I can see, and their quality is decent. They are not as accurate as Google maps. Example: I was in Barcelona last March and the software could find the street fine, but not exactly the house number. That's a a minor annoyance when you're driving and take a left turn where you need a right one.

It is free for up to 10 map downloads (maps change regularly, you decide when to update), otherwise $6.95.

Three caveats:

- I have not had enough experience with its turn-by-turn directions with voice guidance to actually rate this. It seems to work.
- As with any other GPS based navigation software, quality of directions depends on the quality of the received GPS signals and the speed with which you are moving. For a  pedestrian in a city, expect temporarily unclear directions.
- No satellite view

(Added) O yes, one big plus: I asks ony for the permissions it needs.

Answer (score 2):

What will work for you is [Maverick](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codesector.maverick.lite) (or Maverick Pro) for viewing the map, and [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) for generating/downloading the offline map, which you then upload to your Android device to use with Maverick. Also, all tiles viewed in Maverick are cached, so just browsing the area online with Maverick will allow you to see it offline - limited to how much you viewed online (no such limit for Atlas Creator; you just mark a square, set max zoom level, and it grabs all the tiles up to that zoom level.)

As for other features, all are present while online. Placemarking and simple direction (straight line) will work when offline too, but search and driving directions require network connectivity. I don't think any online service allows dumping their search database for offline use, and while offline map applications (e.g. for dedicated car GPS devices) contain searchable POI, they don't have satellite view.